# Does a RasPi case exist that utilizes a key and lock for unattended datacenter usage?

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to find a case that can be mounted via Tapcons or anchors to a cement wall in which the RPi could only be accessed via a lock and key.

Does anyone make something like this? If not, would anyone be interested in making one for me?

Thank you so much and have a great day!

Comment: Questions about shopping and hiring services are off topic per the help page.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest just getting a generic lockabale wallmount enclosure and then mounting the Pi on some standoffs inside it.

For this kind of application you probablly don't want a case that exactly fits the Pi but rather a case that is big enough for all the plugs and sockets to be inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advice not to place the Pi and key together.  Rather make a hole in the wall and place the Pi and power supply inside the datacenter.

This will not only give you a lot more options for choosing case(s), it's also far less prone for abuse.  Once inside the datacenter, people probably have better things to do than to 'pick' your lock circuitry.

Be sure to put the Pi and lock mechanism on the datacenter UPS.  It might sound obviously and stupid that I mention this, but really, as we speak, people are getting denied access to server rooms around the globe during powercut if-we-dont-shutdown-that-box-properly-were-screwed situations.